# Trouble implementing Facebook 'like' button

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, social-networking, facebook-like

This is the code I'm putting on my website:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=5766773068&amp;href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=47&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:47px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

An implemented example URL is:

http://www.scirra.com/blog

Whenever I press 'like', nothing seems to happen, and if I expand the frame size to see what is happened it just says 'error'.

I keep trying to use:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

But it is really temperamental sometimes giving me code other times not.  Do I *have* to specify the URL?  I was under the assumption this was not needed to 'like' the current page.

Please note on my homepage the like button works fine, but the url is specified.  So can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As phadej has noted, you are missing the `href` attribute from your iFrame call. The thing to note from the Like button documentation is this:

> href - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current page.

You are using the iFrame version, so this is why you must include `href`

A useful tool that you might like to bookmark is the [Facebook URL linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) which will show you any errors in your Open Graph tags or missing information, as well as try and help you figure out anything that is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `href` argument set in the src parameter of iframe.

Compare yours code

```
...766773068&amp;href&amp;send=false&a...
```

with generated

```
...76677306&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scirra.com%2Fblog&amp;send=false&a...
```

Comment: Is the HTTP argument mandatory?  I wish it to take the current page url and it not be specified if possible.

Comment: It is a key argument - it tells facebook which page you would to like. As the like-button is inside iframe, it have little knowledge of surrounding page. As API references tells -- "href - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current page." -- implicates it's mandatory for the iframe-version